# Sharepoint 2016 timer service cannot start after applying windows OS patch KB5035855

Tags: windows, sharepoint, windows-services, patch, sharepoint-2016

Currently im facing an issue when i attempt to start the SharePoint Timer Service in windows services. A pop up message appears stating "Windows could not start the SharePoint Timer Service on local computer. Error: 1053. The Service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion"

Any kind souls out there that have resolve this issue or have ideas to share. Please reach out here.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check for Recent Updates:
   Have you applied any updates to your server recently? Sometimes, updates can impact services. Consider running the SharePoint Product and Configuration Wizard on your affected server to see if the error persists.
   If you encounter any specific error messages during the service startup, please share them for further diagnosis.
2. Adjust the Timer Service Recycle Schedule:
   The Timer Service Recycle job might conflict with other long-running timer jobs. To resolve this:

- [Change the schedule for the Timer Service Recycle job so that it doesn’t overlap with other lengthy tasks.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/the-timer-service-failed-to-recycle)
- Ensure that the user account performing this procedure is a member of the Farm Administrators group.

3. Restart the SharePoint Administrative Services:
   First, perform an IISreset to refresh the web services.
   Wait for about 15 minutes to allow any pending operations to complete.
   Then, try to refresh the timer job and restart it.